# Force to use MAC address as DHCP client ID on Debian Buster

Tags: dhcp, debian-buster

Debian Buster dhclient randomly uses its MAC address or a generated DUID-LLT as its DHCP client ID.

Can I force it to always use MAC address instead of the generated DUID-LLT?

I know the option `send dhcp-client-identifier = xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx;`, but it forces me to configure every interface manually with its own MAC address, something I prefer to avoid if possible.

As I said before, it is doing it already, but randomly.

Can it be forced to do it always?

Comment: Doing it "randomly" is a bit unusual, and it's actually the first time I've heard of dhclient sending a DUID on its own... Are you sure the system doesn't actually have two DHCP clients running at the same time? (e.g. dhclient _and_ dhcpcd or systemd-networkd running alongside it?)

Comment: @user1686 Its a badly configured network with a badly configured Windows DHCP server. This is most likely the cause of the problem, but solving it is another issue. The thing is that Debian Buster dhclient sometimes use the MAC address as client ID so it seems that it should be possible to do it always... or so I think.

Comment: @user1686 My Debian machines only uses dhclient; systemd DHCP client is disabled as it comes by default. It isn't an issue of two competing DHCP clients.

Comment: Does the issue remain if you delete stored leases under /var/lib/dhclient (and maybe from the DHCP server as well)?

Comment: @user1686 It generates a new DUID-LLT.

Comment: @user1686 I found the solution. I added it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The solution is simple, but not documented (not on the manpage of `dhclient.conf` at least). You can set the option `send dhcp-client-identifier = hardware` instead of hardcoding a specific MAC address.

Complete example:

```
$ echo "send dhcp-client-identifier = hardware;" >>/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
$ rm /var/lib/dhcp/*
$ systemctl restart networking
```

It configures `dhclient` to send hardware address as client identifier, removes previous leases and restart interfaces with new settings. After this change it will use the MAC address as the client ID of each interface, automatically.

Comment: A total life-saver because as massa says it is not documented. I was having this problem with Debian 10 buster as DHCP client and Windows 2012 Server as DHCP server. I cannot get rid of the 2012, so this has really made my day. Thanks!

Comment: What's really odd is that it still generates the DUID with this option on, it just doesn't appear to use it.  We were having a bunch of problems with our DHCP server issuing new IPs for no reason, so hopefully this fixes it.

Answer (score 6):

Since this change
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=906894
ifupdown had been adding the -i parameter to dhclient.

```
-i     Use a DUID with DHCPv4 clients.
```

But here is a fix: this change
https://salsa.debian.org/debian/ifupdown/-/commit/40eb51499fe71e4fb20c27beea23045c62e9ba07
went to ifupdown 0.8.36 and makes the -i option optional.
This is kind of documented in the (new enough) manpage for /etc/network/interfaces:
man interfaces / INET ADDRESS FAMILY / "The dhcp Method" / Options  / client

```
client client_id
    Client identifier (dhcpcd), or "no" (dhclient)
```

So, for my case the practical solution was to add "client no" to my /etc/network/interfaces, like

```
.....
iface eno1 inet dhcp
    client no
```

which brings the old behaviour, which is: ifup calls dhclient without "-i", as seen here:
https://salsa.debian.org/debian/ifupdown/-/blob/40eb51499fe71e4fb20c27beea23045c62e9ba07/inet.defn#L101
For the record, I look at the command line parameters for confirmation: `ps aux | grep dhclient`

(By the way, to see the logs one can go like: `sudo journalctl | grep -i dhcp | less`)

This way it can talk to a DHCP server that is scared of RFC 4361.

This comes with a bit of fine print:
for Debian 10, I had to backport the ifupdown package.
I have followed https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112160/203082
to obtain locally a `ifupdown_0.8.36~bpo10+1_amd64.deb` package.
After installation, I wasn't able to cleanly restart my networking (probably due to some systemd-related complexities).

So I had to reboot, unfortunately. Then it was able to obtain the IP address as expected.