# Static IP address not being assigned by DHCP server to host on a certain interface of a systemd-networkd bridge

Tags: router, dhcp, systemd, bridge

I've got a box that I configured as a wired/wireless router, using `systemd-networkd` to define a bridge (`br0`) between `enp3s0` (wired) and `wlp1s0` (wireless) interfaces, with the `systemd-networkd` DHCP server running on the bridge. Static leases for clients are defined in the bridge's network configuration file using `[DHCPServerStaticLease]` directives. I'm finding however that the defined static IP is not being given to the client connected on the `enp3s0` interface of the bridge, whereas they are being given to clients connected on `wlp1s0`. The client on `enp3s0` is getting given the IP address `10.0.0.147` from the DHCP pool whereas I want it to be `10.0.0.10` as per the `[DHCPServerStaticLease]` directive below.

Here are the configurations that define the various interfaces:

`/etc/systemd/network/10-br0.netdev`:

```
[NetDev]
Name=br0
Kind=bridge
```

`/etc/systemd/network/15-br0.network`:

```
[Match]
Name=br0

[Network]
Address=10.0.0.1/24
DHCPServer=yes
DNS=10.0.0.1
Domains=lan

[DHCPServer]
PoolOffset=100
PoolSize=100

[DHCPServerStaticLease]
# Wired client - this IP does not get assigned (I've triple checked this MAC and it's correctly entered on client and server)
MACAddress=01:23:45:67:89:10
Address=10.0.0.10

[DHCPServerStaticLease]
# Wireless client - this IP gets assigned correctly
MACAddress=12:34:56:78:90:12
Address=10.0.0.20
```

`/etc/systemd/network/20-lan.network`:

```
[Match]
Name=enp3s0

[Network]
Bridge=br0
```

The wireless interface is provided by `hostapd` in `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`. This contains, among other things, the commands to add the wireless interface to the bridge:

```
interface=wlp1s0
bridge=br0
```

With everything up and running, upon connecting the wired client I don't see any information regarding the IP address assignment in the journal (with debug logging enabled for `systemd-networkd` following the steps in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/12345990)), just that the request was acknowledged, which doesn't seem very helpful to find out what's going on:

```
$ journalctl --unit systemd-networkd -r | grep "br0: DHCPv4"
Jan 01 21:36:59 router systemd-networkd[753]: br0: DHCPv4 server: ACK (0x6c2c7b71)
Jan 01 21:36:59 router systemd-networkd[753]: br0: DHCPv4 server: REQUEST (rebinding/renewing) (0x6c2c7b71)
```

Does anyone see what's wrong with my setup, or at least know how to get more information out of the DHCP server when it's deciding to ignore the static assignment for the wired client?

Comment: did you end up finding an answer? Exactly the same situation here...

Comment: @DaniloBargen no - I ended up switching to dnsmasq for DHCP and static IP assignments which works flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

This appears to be a bug in Systemd <= 253. When clients don't send their MAC address in the DHCP client identifier, then the MAC comparison does not work. In your case, the wireless client probably does send the MAC, while the wired client does not.

- Bug report: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/21368
- Related Debian bug report: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1050098

This was fixed in the following pull request: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/27313

### Client Workaround

As a workaround, ensure that the DHCP client sends the client identifier as part of the DHCP request.

**systemd-networkd**

In case of Systemd's networkd, by default the DUID is used. To change it to the MAC address, add the following network config:

```
[DHCPv4]
ClientIdentifier=mac
```

You can find more information in `man 5 systemd.network`.

**dhclient**

If you use dhclient, you can turn off the use of DUIDs: [Force to use MAC address as DHCP client ID on Debian Buster](https://superuser.com/questions/1553094/force-to-use-mac-address-as-dhcp-client-id-on-debian-buster)

### Solution

Upgrade to Systemd >= 254 or apply a backport of the patch.